# Entity framework - Database First - MVP Pattern

Tags: entity-framework, mvp, ef-database-first

I have a question about the database first aproach with entity framework and MVP/MVVM/MVC pattern.

Im pretty new to entity framework, and im not sure if im thinking right. I have been searching for intormation for some time now, but still did not have a clear answer.

I am used to code first development. So i made my classes with the attributes (Models) manually, and these are stored in the folder 'Models'.

Now, the database first aproach with entity i notice that the classes(models) are created out of the database information.

So, this means that i don't need to create any Models ? And is it still possible to store them nicely in a folder 'Models' ? Or do i leave them in the entity emdx? 
And i only have to create the views and presenters incase of MVP ?

Thanks in advance,
Kevin

Comment: You can do code first from database, if that is what you are looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this info, but the code first of an existing database was not what i ment. The question was, if you choose for a pattern, with database first, i assume you don't need to write the 'models', but only the views and presenters. But is it still possible to put the models created by entity in a seperate folder 'models' to keep it overlooking, or not?

Comment: Ok, that was answered here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b79175eb-fdb5-4478-8ee4-7ea5c466e236/database-first-ef5-how-to-generate-poco-classes-in-another-project?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: Yes! Thats exactly the same scenario. Thats the same how i work. models shouldn't be in the DAL. Thanks a million. I literally have been looking for many hours now.